# Sending push notification to iOS device

Tags: ios, laravel, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to send push notification to the device, on which I have my created pkpass. 
Device is successfully registered for automatic updates, I have its token.

For making push to APNS I'm using package "daim2k5/laravel-push-notification".
I'm using Laravel 5.2, for which it is not very much packages, for 5.3 is more.

But when I'm trying to push, I always get **Adapter APNS does not support 2a984ecb2a947786dc4479d25109a172 token's device** (token is in this format, its not real token, just example)

```
$devices = \PushNotification::DeviceCollection(array(
        \PushNotification::Device('2a984ecb2a947786dc4479d25109a172', array('badge' => 1))
    ));

$r = \PushNotification::app([
        'environment' =>'production',
        'certificate' =>'awdrca.pem',
        'passPhrase'  =>'password',
        'service'     =>'apns'
    ])->to($devices) ->send('Test');
```

Is the token I have really invalid? Or is there error some where else?

Comment: Check the certificates. Also check : https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification/issues/96

Comment: Certificate should be ok, i'm using it for creating Pkpasses too, and they are working fine.

Comment: @Priyal it seems string length for tokken is not correct. I have only 32 chars, and the gyu robschuh is checking length 64 chars. But i'm saving whole token, which i received.

Comment: upload your pem file and enter device token here  http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/ and check.

Comment: @V12 after submit it loads emty page only :\

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are getting correct formatted device token from the iOS device here is an example to get the right supported format for the device token.

```
NSString * token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
    //Format token as you need:
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"%@", token);
```

Secondly try using davibennun laravel-push-notification package it is simple and easy to configure for both iOS and Android.
https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification

Comment: I am using the package you mentioned. However I cannot set the expiration period of the push notification. Do you know how to set the apns_expiration as mentioned in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1  ?